# sed: return all lines between matching patterns and quit

Tags: linux, sed

I want to extract only the lines that will restore a specific table from a mysql backup file.  The following works.

`` zcat /mnt/backup/full-replication.gz | sed -n -e '/DROP TABLE.*`account_codes`/,/UNLOCK TABLES/p' > account_codes.sql ``

However, the backup file it 9GB in size, so I'd like to stop searching once the ending match has been found.  So in the sed part of the above command I could add {p;q} instead of p at the end like this:

`` zcat /mnt/backup/full-replication.gz | sed -n -e '/DROP TABLE.*`account_codes`/,/UNLOCK TABLES/{p;q}' > account_codes.sql ``

That stops, but after the "from" match, not the "to" match.  Essentially the output is then only the first line of the whole block.

`` DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `account_codes`; ``

How can I fix this so that the `q` command only takes effect at the end matching pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264962/print-lines-of-a-file-between-two-matching-patterns), which I used to modify my sed command as followings:

`` zcat /mnt/backup/full-replication.gz | sed -n -e '/DROP TABLE.*`account_codes`/,/UNLOCK TABLES/{p;/UNLOCK TABLES/q}' > account_codes.sql ``

Essentially it tells sed to find the matching lines and then quit when it finds the next "UNLOCK TABLES" string in the file.

In the mysql backup file the "UNLOCK TABLES;" in followed by (for example)

```
--
-- Table structure for table `account_table`
--
```

However, if I modify the sed command as following

`` zcat /mnt/backup/full-replication.gz | sed -n -e '/DROP TABLE.*`account_codes`/,/UNLOCK TABLES/{p;/-- Table structure for table/q}' > account_codes.sql ``

sed does not stop when it finds that string.  I'm not experienced enough with sed to figure out why not.  Maybe someone can leave a comment to clarify this?